# GitHUB - fail to push submodules with HTTPS

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a repo with some AWS submodules and when I try to issue:

**git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand**

I get this:

**Pushing submodule 'lib/AWS/Device-Shadow-for-AWS-IoT-embedded-sdk'**

Here I get a popup window:

[image: GitHUB Sign in]

And I select `Sign in with a code`, I get the code and visit the URL it point me to and I issue the device activation successfully and press the `Authorize git-ecosystem` button, I get `Congratulations, you're all set!` and then this:

**remote: Permission to aws/Device-Shadow-for-AWS-IoT-embedded-sdk.git denied to XYZ.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/aws/Device-Shadow-for-AWS-IoT-embedded-sdk.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Unable to push submodule 'lib/AWS/Device-Shadow-for-AWS-IoT-embedded-sdk'**

How can I resolve this?

I follow some suggestions I saw to remove the current credentials from Windows credential manager as well as use GitHUB CLI to set the HTTP authentication login, I did those with no change in the above behavior.